# onClickListeners in bindView() or extended views

Tags: android

In a list view, I usually define button onClickListeners in the bindView() method of my custom `CursorAdapter`. For example :

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ...
        viewHolder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                ...
                new myDao().updateSomethingInDB(myObject);
                getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(myContentProviderUri, null);            
            }
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

This seems really wasteful as anonymous inner classes have to be created in the `view.setOnClickListener()` method every time `bindView()` is run.

Would it make sense to create extended views that have their listeners defined within their own class definition instead? So instead of using a `Button` in my list view's item layout, i would be using extended Button views like `LikeButton`, `DislikeButton`, `UpVoteButton` etc. In this way all the behaviour(like updating the database, notifying the content resolver etc.) is encapsulated in the extended view rather than in the activity/fragment ? Does it violate any design principles(like maybe MVC)?

Comment: Brother your question unclear...

Comment: @HareshChhelana sorry about that. i have attempted to clarify it with some code. pls have a look.

Comment: if you have list item more than one child click listener then it is right way otherwise you can use list itemclick listener outside adapter.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it make sense to create extended views that have their listeners defined within their own class definition instead?

yes. it make sense to create compound/custom views that implement their own inner widget events.
also it can be potentially much more efficient to instantiate only one time the listener within the compound view then creating new instance of the listener every call to `bindView()`
of course the decision to do so is depends on the specific use case, and what's their dependency and relation with the activity or fragment they reside in.

> In this way all the behaviour(like updating the database, notifying the content resolver etc.) is encapsulated in the extended view rather than in the activity/fragment ?

I don't see any problem with that as long that you know what you are doing.  and it's important to know exactly what you are doing because there are lot's of traps you can fall in if you are not careful:

- canceling or dissmising listeners of network operations or async tasks at the right time of the view cycle
- releasing references that can cause memory leaks if not released at the right time of the view and activity lifeycle
- "binding" and "un-binding" between the DTO object to the compound view each time it recycled when used inside list view

and much more...

Comment: one of the things i am worried about is mixing the model and the view components of the MVC architecture. If i go with the approach of incorporating the database manipulation and other data-related behaviour in extended views, i fear the code is going to get really messy really fast.

Comment: the fact that you handle click events inside the compound view does not say at all that all the logic should be there also.  for example: in my own applications - doing operations such as you "like" and "dislike", I perform all the network operations from a Service that starting with the right command and parameters from the custom view. when the Service command finish - the Service itself doing the database/content provider changes, and sending broadcast indicating my Loaders that new content availible...

Comment: So in the onClickListener of your compound view class, you have a call to a service? Or do you make the call to the service in the activity/fragment class?

Comment: lot's of time I'm doing the startService() call  directly from the view

Answer (score 0):

I dont find any violation of designing principles. I have implemented the similar thing in my app and the app works flowlessy in any devices.

And on ur concern about designing principles, u shldnt bother much about that as fas as ur getting ur job done wihtout compromising app's performance.

User never know how the app is designed. what they bother about is that, yes! this app is working fast and smoothly. i should use this.

U can know more about listview's in google i/o here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Don't you think performance would take a hit as well with this approach because the bindView() runs for every list view item and also every time an item scrolls into visible area of the screen?

Comment: nope. not unless ur listview has some 1000-2000 rows. Also, u should use a different object class for row content and then set Setters and Getters. I have updated my answer with a link to googl's i/o about listview. it is of about 1 hour but that one hour is worth spending